# </my-date-picker> using ngmodel how should i convert date format and send

Tags: angular2-template

I am getting date like this `2018-10-17T00:00:00.000Z` i should convert to `17.10.18` and send through [(ngModel)] by using my date picker

Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

got solution.

`var availYear = moment(availDate).format("YYYY");
        var availMonth = moment(availDate).format("M");
        var availDay = moment(availDate).format("DD");
        this.model = { date: { year: availYear, month: availMonth, day: availDay } };`